# ClassCircularityError thrown by Class.forName while transform TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl class

Tags: java, circular-reference, javaagents

I'm trying to write a Java Agent to intercept the application. When the class is being transformed, I need to get the parent class information. So the Class.forName() method will be called to get the parent class. When application try to create a MulticastSocket object, the TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl class will be transformed on Windows platform, and then the Class.forName("java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl") will be called in the agent's transform method. However, the ClassCircularityError will be thrown. **This only happens above JRE version 1.7.0_71 and 1.8.0_25.** The application works well using the old JRE version. I have simplify the application to reproduce the issue. So anyone meets this issue before? Can someone give some advice?

This is the agent's transform method:

```
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className,
            Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
            byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (className.endsWith("java/net/TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl"))
            try {
                Class.forName("java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Error e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
    }
```

This is the application need to be intercepted.

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

And this is the error thrown:

```
java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/net/TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl
[Loaded java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl from D:\Share\jre1.7.0_76\lib\rt.jar]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.init(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.ca.instrumentation.TestClassFileTransformer.transform(TestClassFileTransformer.java:16)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.DefaultDatagramSocketImplFactory.createDatagramSocketImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.createImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.MulticastSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.MulticastSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at test.test.main(test.java:11)
```

Comment: Can someone help on this?